# crypto-js cant decrypt what it encrypted

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I need to encrypt a sting with javascript using AES CBC no pad, pass the IV and encrypted data as HEX over HTTP, then decrypt with javascript on the server side.

The decryption function works, in that I can correctly decrypt data ecrypted using hurlant AS3 libraries correctly.  However, the below encryption is not working - the result cannot be decrypted using the decrypt function, nor can it be decrypted using the hurant demo at: http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/

Instead of the actual data, I am using "1234" as the message in this example.

I have searched and found no documentation for any of this library or its functions, beyond the quickstart guide which only has trivial cases, so everything is by trial and error.  I have tried hundreds of variations of the below.

Example generated IV as Hex: "15ae89d17f632d21f0cda04734d38694"

Example generated encrypte data as HEX: "44ddf295"

Example message: "15ae89d17f632d21f0cda04734d3869444ddf295"

Can anyone see what is wrong in my encrypt() function?

```
// this function doesnt work - the resultant message (which is 
//       IV+Ecypted text all as HEX cannot be decrypted.
function encrypt() {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421888888');
    var IVLEN = 16; // Im guessing this is 16 bytes.
    var iv= CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(IVLEN);
    var encrypted;
    var message;

    encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("1234", key, { iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });

    message = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv) + CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext);

    var test = decrypt(message);  // throws a malformed UTF-8 exception

    alert (test); // should alert "1234"

    return message;

}

// this function works perfectly with data generated using HURLANT crypto libs.
function decrypt(data) {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421888888');
    var ivHexStr, iv;
    var encMessageHexStr;
    var IVLEN = 32;  // This is 16 bytes, as one byte is 2 Hex chars.
    var encrypted = {};
    var decrypted;
    var result;

    ivHexStr = data.substring(0,IVLEN);
    encMessageHexStr = data.substring(IVLEN);

    iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivHexStr);
    encrypted.key        = key;
    encrypted.iv         = iv;
    encrypted.ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encMessageHexStr);

    decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });

    result = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);

    return(result);
}; //decrypt()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CBC mode padding is required.  Neither CFB or OFB need padding.

[CryptoJS supports the following modes:](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Block_Modes_and_Padding)

- CBC (the default)
- CFB
- CTR
- OFB
- ECB

[And CryptoJS supports the following padding schemes:](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Block_Modes_and_Padding)

- Pkcs7 (the default)
- Iso97971
- AnsiX923
- Iso10126
- ZeroPadding
- NoPadding

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been using it with no padding between Hurlant (encrypting with no padding) and javascript (decrypting with no padding) without issue for many years, so it does work.  Javascript to javascript should be easy!  There is no compatible padding scheme between Hurlant AS3 and crypto js (hurlant only has none or PKCS#5, cryptojs only has: Pkcs7,Iso97971,AnsiX923,Iso10126,ZeroPadding,NoPadding)

Comment: Not using padding isn't isn't possible with a proper CBC algorithm, there are ways [CTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing) that can make CBC look like it's not using padding but it's really using part of the ciphertext for padding. I have no doubt that you are having problems because of this configuration, looking at the hurlant demo it is padding with something even when you choose none, but pkcs5 is the same as pkcs7 just a smaller block size (which isn't appropriate for aes) so I'm guessing it's just bad naming. So pad pkcs5/7 or switch to CFB or OFB mode.